# PyQt5 unable to launch an app at Ubuntu because of xcb was found but cannot load

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm facing with an issue that app is not launching in ubuntu whereas works like charm on windows. My error is:

```
Cannot move to target thread (0x254fca0)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc.
```

then I saw people that says enable export `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` I pasted the output below. Then I see people facing with same issue at [this link](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1373) but they was not succeed too. I'm pretty new on Ubuntu. So if you can help I will glad.

Also one said that make with sudo. I tried with sudo and it gave ubuntu software error. Whenever I try with sudo Pc try to report error.

[My output for qt debug(too long for stackoverflow)](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/pm9fjqZ75y/)